# Flex, Grails Security over HTTP - How to example?

Tags: apache-flex, security, http, grails

I'm writing an application, Flex front-end & Grails back-end, in which I need to integrate security. All the information around Grails gives me the impression to be well suited for when your client is written in HTML but how can I use Flex's HTTPService to integrate into it? Could anybody point me into the right direction?

Regards,
Lars

Answer (score 1):

Hi Lars
I'd suggest having a read of Mike Hugo's article on writing Grails plug-ins in Groovymag
http://www.groovymag.com/main.issues.description/id=6/
This will give you an insight as to how to gain access to the application context etc.
Also have a look out for Sebastien Arbogast's blog and this article:
http://www.pubbs.net/201002/grails/49092-grails-user-grails-flex-blazeds-and-spring-security-integration.html

Combine this with some articles like this:
http://www.gridshore.nl/2008/07/14/integration-spring-security-acegi-and-flex-3-the-sequel/

Also have a look at the Spring-Flex project. 
http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex
Christophe Coenraets and Jeremy Grelle's blogs are worth taking a look at too.

http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/03/new-spring-blazeds-test-drive-available-flex-4-blazeds-4-and-spring-blazeds-integration-1-0-3/

http://blog.springsource.com/author/jgrelle/

This is probably what I'd look at first:
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2009-develop/integrating-spring-with-blazeds-and-livecycle-data-services/

Also:
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/integrating-spring-and-flex/

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for [returning XML](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.7%20XML%20and%20JSON%20Responses) from a Grails Controller, which can then be consumed by Flex's HTTPService.
For security, check out the [Spring Security Core Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).